# Enable/disable nested form fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form with checkboxes and text fields. I would like to be able to have the text fields only be enabled if the text box for that specific nested form is clicked/enabled. It is currently hard coded to enable/disable fields if the "custom" text box is set. How can I have javascript update these textbox attributes on the fly?

Form.erb now

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :client_prices do |def_price_form| %>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class='span10'>
      <% if def_price_form.object.custom == true  %>
        <%= def_price_form.input :custom, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span1' } %>
        <% end %>
        <%= def_price_form.input :visit_type, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span2' } %>
        <%= def_price_form.input :price, :wrapper => :prepend, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span2' }, :label => "Price" do %>
          <%= content_tag :span, "$", :class => "add-on" %>
          <%= def_price_form.input_field :price %>
          <%= def_price_form.link_to_remove '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'.html_safe, :class => 'btn btn-danger', :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span3 pull-left' } %>
          <%end%>
      <% else %>
        <%= def_price_form.input :custom, :hidden => false, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span1' } %>
        <%= def_price_form.input :visit_type, disabled: true,  :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span2' } %>
        <%= def_price_form.input :price, :wrapper => :prepend, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'span2' }, :label => "Price" do %>
          <%= content_tag :span, "$", :class => "add-on" %>
          <%= def_price_form.input_field :price, disabled: true %>
          <%end%>
      <%end%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add a custom price", :client_prices, :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

HTML generated by RoR here
http://jsfiddle.net/59AXJ/

Comment: Provide the HTML generated by this page by viewing the source on a rendered page in the browser. This will make it easier to view the DOM and someone can help you out with the correct JS. Unless you are using coffeescript.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested"?  You can't put a `<form>` inside another `<form>`.

Comment: It is a term in rails, you can "nest" forms from one model inside a parent model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the attribute name from the checkbox that is clicked.  Then finds inputs that have similar names, those are the inputs that we will toggle "disabled".

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    var thisCheckbox = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var text = $("label[for=" + id + "]").text().toLowerCase();
    var name = $(this).attr("name").replace("[" + text + "]", "");
    $("input[name*='" + name + "']").each(function () {
        var thisInput = $(this);
        if (thisInput.attr("disabled")) {
            thisInput.removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            thisInput.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            thisCheckbox.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbw65/  <-- test it out

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it's impossible to make this on fly, but you can write some unique function on javascript, wich will connect some input with  some checkbox by their css class. Something like this (code on CoffeeScript):

```
changeCheckbox: (class_value) =>
  $('[type=checkbox] '+class_value)). on 'check', (e) ->
    $input = $(e.currentTarget)
      if !$input.prop("checked")
        $("input "+class_value).prop('disabled', false)
      else
        $("input "+class_value).prop('disabled', true)
```

After that, you just need to add some class for connected checkbox and inputs.